# How to retrive the original position of an axis to Vector3?

Tags: unity

```
float x = Random.Range(-1f , 1f) * magnitude;
        float y = Random.Range(-1f , 1f) * magnitude;

        transform.localPosition = new Vector3(x, y, originalPos.z);
```

Here I'm trying to retrive the original position of z(without any changes) to the vector3. But in visual studio 2017 is showing an error like this

[image]

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've failed to define a variable called `originalPos` somewhere that the compiler can find it.

You could write something like this:

```
 // Define the variable we want to use, and copy the old values into it.
 Vector3 originalPos = transform.localPosition;

 float x = Random.Range(-1f , 1f) * magnitude;
 float y = Random.Range(-1f , 1f) * magnitude;

 transform.localPosition = new Vector3(x, y, originalPos.z);
```

Or, even more concisely:

```
 // Create a copy of the local position that we can modify.
 Vector3 modifiedPos = transform.localPosition;

 // Store our changes directly into this local variable.
 modifiedPos.x = Random.Range(-1f , 1f) * magnitude;
 modifiedPos.y = Random.Range(-1f , 1f) * magnitude;
 // Since we didn't modify z, it keeps the old value we copied from local position.

 // Copy our local variable to the transform's local position.
 transform.localPosition = modifiedPos;
```